# Interpolate and add percentage for transform: Invalid property value

Tags: sass

I'm trying to interpolate a value and add it into a transform translate string like this:

```
@for $x from 1 through 30 {
    @for $y from 1 through 30 {

      $xt: calc(#{$x} * 100%);
      $yt: calc(#{$y} * 100%);

      .stone-0#{$x}0#{$y} {
        transform: translate(#{$xt}, -#{$yt});
      }
    }
  }
```

But the output I'm getting is:

```
.stone-0204 {
    transform: translate(calc(2 * 100%), -calc(4 * 100%));
}
```

How can I get the output:

```
.stone-0204 {
    transform: translate(200%, -400%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved with:

```
.stone-0#{$x}0#{$y} {
  transform: translate(percentage($x), -#{percentage($y)});
}
```